# does function/routine present in the .dll runs faster?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, function, dll

As I am new to c++,I wanted know does the function/procedure/routine present within the .dll(dynamic link library) file execute faster then the normal function/procedure/routine present within the same file? or to make my code run faster whether i should use multithreads ?. kindly provide some bloggers link, if you people know please answer this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1: No. 2: Multithreading doesn't make programs run faster, but it makes programming harder. Stay away from multithreading until you have a very firm grasp of singlethreaded programs, especially how to debug them.

Comment: There may be an overhead with DLLs and that is the loading time.  The OS has to either load the DLL into memory at start of program execution or on demand.  The OS may also elect to swap DLL code to the hard disk to make room for other DLLs.

Comment: Only use DLLs when necessary.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would expect that calling a DLL function will have a little overhead, not the other way around as you suggest. According to this [Overhead of DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030043/overhead-of-dll) this overhead is very little, if any.

As you mention multithresding, I think I understand the source of your confusion. There no connection between DLLs and multithreading! DLL calls are synchronized, just as calling functions from within the executable is. If you want to execute them on a separate thread, you just create a separate thread and call the DLL function from there.